# Handle promise rejection with md-on-load

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, angular-material

I'm using the `md-on-load` directive with `<md-select>` because my options are loaded asynchronisly and I can't find a way to handle promise rejection (i.e. if I wasn't able to fetch my options).

I don't have specific UX wishes for that but at the moment the spinner will continue to spin forever if the promise is rejected. The only idea I come up here is to handle myself the promise rejection, store an error message, and return a success to `md-on-load` in both cases...

If there is a simple unofficial directive that handles this case, that could work too.

For now, this is my code (ES6):

```
getCustomers() {
    return this.customerService.getAll().then((customers) => {
        this.customers = customers;
        this.customersErrorMessage = null;
    }, (error) => {
        this.customersErrorMessage = 'Unexpected error, please retry';
        this.$q.resolve();
    });
  }
```

And so I can display `customersErrorMessage` in my interface. But the dropdown of `<md-select>` will remain visible and blank until you click outside (the spinner is no more here though).

Comment: do you mind posting what code you've got so far?

Comment: yep, done now ;-)